# PHP $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] correct use

Tags: php

noob question here

I'm building a interactive web site using php, and i decided to do one interative menu. Well, my menu consists in one file called menu.php.

```
<?php
    echo "<ul>
        <li><a href='".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/menu/register.php'>Cadastro</a><br></li>
        </ul>";
?>
```

I don't know why, but the when i click on this link it appears like that

htpp://localhost/my_site/**localhost**/menu/register.php

EDIT: How can i delete that additional localhost?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

That is because you are not using the `http://` prefix. You would have to use

```
   <li><a href='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/menu/register.php'></li>
```

(assuming `http://` is the only protocol your site can be on)

However, if you have a fixed site structure, consider using relative paths that work just as well, but with less headache:

```
 <li><a href='/menu/register.php'></li>
```

Comment: If  i use that, when i use that menu on another page that is in a different directory it fails, cuz it surch for a directory called menu it it doesn't exists

Comment: @Kleber not if you use `/menu/register.php`. That is an absolute path

Answer (score 6):

[`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server) contains just the name of the web server/virtual host:

> `'SERVER_NAME'`
> The name of the server host under which the current script is executing. If the script is running on a virtual host, this will be the value defined for that virtual host.

In your case it’s `localhost`. And appending a path like `/menu/register.php` to it results in the relative path:

```
localhost/menu/register.php
```

Now when you use that URI reference in a document that’s base URI is `http://localhost/my_site/` (or a similar URI having the same path prefix), that relative path `localhost/menu/register.php` gets resolved by the client to:

```
http://localhost/my_site/localhost/menu/register.php
```

That’s the reason for the output you’re getting.

So what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

Just use relative URIs.

```
<li><a href='/menu/register.php'>Cadastro</a></li>
```

(You can ditch the `<br>` too. Use CSS padding if you want padding.)

Comment: I would omit that "/" in the beginning, so that it runs both under "http://www.example.com/" and "http://www.example.com/temporary_dir/".

Comment: I wouldn't so that it runs both on `http://example.com/` and `http://example.com/a-subsection/`.

Answer (score 1):

You must write like this:

```
echo "<ul>
    <li><a href='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/menu/register.php'>Cadastro</a><br></li>
    </ul>";
```

Or simple

```
echo "<ul>
    <li><a href='/menu/register.php'>Cadastro</a><br></li>
    </ul>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just omit the

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

and use relative pathing.

Answer (score 1):

good practice is not to use the server name in a href's

```
<a href="/menu/register.php">register</a>
```

or

```
<a href="menu/register.php">register</a>
```

should work just fine

if you really needed to use the server name you could use:

```
<a href='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/menu/register.php'>Cadastro</a>
```

the additional localhost is because the browser interprets it as a string and not a URL

Answer (score -1):

I would also recommend using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] over $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] that Ankur Kumar Singh said in a comment.

`<li><a href='".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/menu/register.php'>Cadastro</a><br></li>`

This worked for me and got rid of the local host issue on my sites.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue unfortunately. The URL is missing the protocol part, making the link a relative one, that will resolve to the same `htpp://localhost/my_site/localhost/menu/register.php` in the question. 
The fix would to inlude the protocol (e.g. `http://`): 
`<li><a href='http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/menu/register.php'>Cadastro</a><br></li>`