# concatenate URL in php

Tags: php

```
 $hostName= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; 

 <a href="<?php echo $hostName; ?>/category/supplier/<?php echo $id; ?>" class="pull-right">
```

I have to concatenate the hostName in my URL. But when i concatenate the above URL i am getting the URL in the below format.

```
 http://localhost/project/public/core/country/localhost/category/supplier/2a0901d0-bf9a-11e7-91e1-1916b20e4c9c
```

But actually the URL i am expecting is

```
 http://localhost/category/supplier/2a0901d0-bf9a-11e7-91e1-1916b20e4c9c
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: This has been answered already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128474/php-serverserver-name-correct-use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP $\_SERVER\['SERVER\_NAME'\] correct use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128474/php-serverserver-name-correct-use)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add `http://` or `https://` before `<?php echo $hostName; ?>` in anchor tag href.